# Find minimum in array of dictionaries?

Tags: javascript

I have something like :

```
var array = [
{'a':3,'b':4},
{'a':1,'b':8},
{'a':9,'b':7}]
```

What is an elegant *one line* to find the min/max of the key `'a'` (max=9, min = 1) ?
I know it is simple but i couldn't find a one line solution only loops.

Comment: What exactly is the expected result?

Comment: I just edited, thanks. max here is 9 and min is 1

Comment: how about `Math.min(...array.map(x => x.a))`

Comment: So what is the result, precisely? `1` or `9` or `{ a: 9, b: 7 }` or `{ a: 1, b: 8 }` or `{ min: 1, max: 9 }` or `{ min: { a: 1, b: 8 }, max: { a: 9, b: 7 } }` or something else? Countless options, no example, no effort, no surprise it got downvoted.

Comment: thanks @gog i guess its that simple I am just new to js.

Comment: I wish the new generation of JS coders stopped looking for inefficient one liners and focus on performance and readability.. Wait, did I just made an old man rant?

Comment: @gotiredofcoding Not my downvote, but people do tent to downvote questions that don't show any effort, as they come across like "do my work for me" questions.

Comment: Use the static and instance methods of [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods). Take your pick: `const values = array.map(({ a }) => a); const [ minValue, maxValue ] = [ Math.min(...values), Math.max(...values) ]; const [ minObjects, maxObjects ] = [ array.filter(({ a }) => a === minValue), array.filter(({ a }) => a === maxValue) ];`.

Comment: Here's a useless solution that only traverses the array once to get both min and max: `const [min, max] = array.reduce(([min, max], { a }) => [a < min ? a : min, a > max ? a : max], [Infinity, -Infinity])`.

Comment: > calls us childish
> engages in childish behavior in response to valid criticism about the nature of your question

wut

Comment: Consider `const minMaxObjects = (array, property) => { let min = Infinity, max = -Infinity; const map = array.groupToMap((object) => { if(object[property] < min){ min = object[property]; } if(object[property] > max){ max = object[property]; } return object[property]; }); return { min: map.get(min), max: map.get(max) }; }; const { min, max } = minMaxObjects(array, "a");`, using [`groupToMap`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/groupToMap). Single iteration, yields an array of all objects with minimum value, and another array with maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Logic**

- Create a simple array of the required nodes.
- Use [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get the maximum.

```js
const array = [{ a: 3, b: 4 },{ a: 1, b: 8 },{ a: 9, b: 7 }];
const max = Math.max(...array.map(({ a }) => a));
console.log(max);
```

Apply the same logic for min as well and use [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)

```js
const array = [{ a: 3, b: 4 },{ a: 1, b: 8 },{ a: 9, b: 7 }];
const nodes = array.map(({ a }) => a);
const maxMin = { max: Math.max(...nodes), min: Math.min(...nodes)};
console.log(maxMin);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```js
var array = [
  { a: 3, b: 4 },
  { a: 1, b: 8 },
  { a: 9, b: 7 },
];

const arrayA = array.map((v) => v.a);

const maxA = Math.max(...arrayA);
const minA = Math.min(...arrayA);

console.log({ minA, maxA });
```

Comment: Technically it's not a *one-liner*, though.

Comment: "do something like this" without explanatory commentary isn't particularly useful.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to keep it in 1 line.

```js
var array = [
  { a: 3, b: 4 },
  { a: 1, b: 8 },
  { a: 9, b: 7 },
];
const result = {
  min: Math.min(...array.map((x) => x.a)),
  max: Math.max(...array.map((x) => x.a)),
};
console.log(result);
```